# Sending url form Model to Template in Django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am trying to return a link to a view but it wont work because it has a url inside of it, currently getting KeyError
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sJNd.png)

Is there a way to return urls such as:
 {% url "tickets:agregar_seguimiento" object.id %}
to a template.

I am currently returning it as format_html but it is not working this way.

Here is my code:

```
#models.py

    class ClienteTicketAplicaPriveedor(TicketTipo):
    def get_botones_admin(self):
        return format_html('<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url tickets:agregar_seguimiento object.id %}" >Agregar mensaje de seguimiento</a>')
```

#on template I get the values for this button the following way
    {{object.get_botones_cliente}}

This is only working for plain html at the moment

I am working with Django 1.9

Comment: please post the full error in the question and not as an image. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it formats as a html safe string. So try using url reverse function and concat it with the string you return from the below finction.

Try using the below code in models.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('tickets:agregar_seguimiento', kwargs={'id':self.id})
```

For more detailed reference [django.core.urlresolvers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/)

Comment: Thanks Aswin! This issue had me really stuck!